# ImportError: no module name 'pyspark' when module executed

Tags: python, import, pyspark

if I run in my terminal as follows:

python3

> > import pyspark

ALL GOOD

if I run in my terminal as follows:
sudo python3

> > import pyspark

it throws an ImportError: No Module named 'pyspark'

In both situations I use this python version:
Python 3.5.2 (default, Sep 10 2016, 08:21:44) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux

EDIT: print sys path

this is the print output for python3 command:

```
>>> print(sys.path)
['', '/home/jlr/spark-1.6.0/python', '/home/jlr/spark-1.6.0/python/build', '/home/rsk/spark-1.6.0/python', '/home/jlr/spark/python', '/home/jlr/Documents/portfolio/zz_movies', '/usr/lib/python35.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.5', '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tweepy-3.6.0-py3.5.egg', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

this is the print output for sudo python3 command:

```
>>> print(sys.path)
['', '/usr/lib/python35.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.5', '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tweepy-3.6.0-py3.5.egg', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

EDIT2:

I have installed spark in this way:

```
wget http://d3kbcqa49mib13.cloudfront.net/spark-1.6.0.tgz
$ tar xvf spark-1.6.0.tgz
```

and I have not used pip install command.

Comment: `sudo` and `non sudo` users install pip packages in different locations. So if you do `sudo pip install pyspark` it will be accessible to `sudo` users.

Comment: first of all I run python3 so I would not use pip, secondly, I have not installed pyspark with pip but downloaded spark and build spark with sudo command. I used sudo sbt/sbt assembly

Comment: if I run pip3 install pyspark I get "Collecting pyspark
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyspark (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pyspark
" and I have tried it and this is why I build spark.

Comment: kiran is correct, sudo and non sudo are installed in different places. Run sudo wget http://d3kbcqa49mib13.cloudfront.net/spark-1.6.0.tgz and that will fix your problem.

Comment: the issue is that I run originaly sudo wget .... and for sudo python all works .... the problem is when I run python3 only ... but anyway, I understand the problem.